# How can I specialize this template class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Suppose I have a class

```
template<template<typename, std::size_t> class Child, typename T, std::size_t D>
class tuple;
```

How can I specialize this for `D = 2` with a `Child` type which has only one `typename` template argument?

I've tried

```
template<template<typename> class Child>
struct foo
{
    template<typename U, typename V>
    using type = Child<U>;
};

template<template<typename> class Child, typename T>
class tuple<typename foo<Child>::type, T, 2>;
```

by the compiler says that the template argument `Child` is not deducible ...

Comment: A specialization is a subset. If you change the parameter type it's no longer a subset. You should also clarify the question with a more complete example of what you want to pass in as `Child`, and how you're looking to use it.

Answer (score 2):

> with a Child type which has only one typename template argument?

You can't. Your original template requires a template template parameter with two template parameters, one a type parameter and the other a non-type parameter. A template that can take only one parameter does not match that (and neither would `template<typename U, typename V>` which takes two *type* template parameters).

Trying to indirect through an alias template member in a class also can't work, because nested names are non-deduced contexts.

(Also `Child` is not a type, it is a template.)